# Conversion tracking for Google AdWords that works with a form's submit button

Tags: javascript, php, forms, google-ads-api

I want to put the tracking code on my website but the instructions on [Google's Instructions](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6095821) tells you how to do it by a normal link. I have my form set up with the post method that goes to a php include that emails the form results and then it goes to an thank you page. How do I set it up for the submit button/form to properly work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually use a javascript `onClick` function, which is added to your form's submit button.

If you scroll down a bit on the link that you posted (https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6095821) you should see the section titled "Tracking clicks on links or buttons as conversions". Look for and click "Setting up an onclick handler for conversions" and you will see the instructions.

Comment: So will it still work with the post method of the form if I put the php file's address there?

Comment: Yes, because the javascript will execute before the form is actually submitted.

Comment: So should I just exclude the URL like this then? onclick="goog_report_conversion
  ()"

Comment: The form still works properly, going to check on Monday if the tracking works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays there is a built-in way for AdWords to do async tag firing. It is described in this article.

In brief you would need to change setting in AdWords it would generate you async tag, which you load with the DOM, and activate with onClick handler.

---

Example:

```
<a onclick="goog_report_conversion ('http://example.com/your-link')"
href="http://example.com/your-link">Download now!</a>
```